# Azure Blob SAS token from APEX

Tags: rest, salesforce, azure-blob-storage, apex, azure-rest-api

I'm trying to generate correct SAS token to Azure Blob file storage with Salesforce APEX code. I have managed to achieve that in Java but I'm struggling with APEX. When using token generated by APEX I'm getting this response:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:b0dffeb8-701e-005c-328e-e55882000000
Time:2023-09-12T15:36:13.3757050Z</Message>
    <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was rac
2023-09-12T15:33:47Z
2023-09-12T15:49:47Z
/blob/ittstsa/ittstsafs



2023-01-03
c






</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

while my code looks like

```
private String generateSasTokenString(final String sourceName) {
        final Datetime sasExpires = Datetime.now().addMinutes(15);
        final Datetime sasStarts = Datetime.now().addMinutes(-1);
        final String versionDate = '2023-01-03';
        final String signedPermissions = 'rac';
        final String signedStarts = sasStarts.formatGmt('YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
        final String signedExpires = sasExpires.formatGmt('YYYY-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'');
        final String signedService = 'c';
        final String signedIdentifier = '';
        final String signedIp = '';
        final String signedProtocol = '';
        final String rscc='';
        final String rscd='';
        final String rsce='';
        final String rscl='';
        final String rsct='';
        final String stringToSign = signedPermissions + '\n' +
                signedStarts + '\n' +
                signedExpires + '\n' +
                '/blob/ittstsa/ittstsafs\n' +
                signedIdentifier + '\n' +
                signedIp + '\n' +
                signedProtocol + '\n' +
                versionDate + '\n' +
                signedService + '\n' +
                '\n' +
                rscc + '\n' +
                rscd + '\n' +
                rsce + '\n' +
                rscl + '\n' +
                rsct;
        System.debug('stringToSign--->'+stringToSign);
        final Blob unicodeKey = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('___');
        final Blob blobData = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA256', Blob.valueOf(stringToSign), unicodeKey);
        System.debug('!!! ->>>' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blobData));
        final String sasToken = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blobData), 'UTF-8');
        final String sasTokenString = sourceName + '?sv=' + versionDate + '&st=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signedStarts, 'UTF-8') + '&se=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(signedExpires, 'UTF-8') + '&sr=' + signedService  + '&sp=' + signedPermissions + '&sig=' + sasToken;
        return sasTokenString;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So after further investigation including debugging Java library offered by Azure I have found out that one blank line was missing in the string used to generate SAS token. Here is correct string:

```
final String stringToSign = signedPermissions + '\n' +
                signedStarts + '\n' +
                signedExpires + '\n' +
                '/blob/' + getAccountName() + '/' + containerAuthData.DeveloperName + '\n' +
                signedIdentifier + '\n' +
                signedIp + '\n' +
                signedProtocol + '\n' +
                versionDate + '\n' +
                signedService + '\n' +
                '\n' +
                '\n' +
                rscc + '\n' +
                rscd + '\n' +
                rsce + '\n' +
                rscl + '\n' +
                rsct;
```